# What is the best way to test Awareness Api Accuracy?

Tags: android, google-awareness

I'm using Awareness API, and wondering, what is the best way to test is during development, on a device (not an emulator)?

I want to emulate to test its accuracy

> location / activity / weather

changes for example.

How can I achieve it?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is too broad . Please add some code snippet or example :)

Comment: It is a general question, though.
I'm trying to figure out how can I emulate the activity change, for example.

Comment: Not able to get your point for this :(

Comment: I want to have some testings so I can get a sense of how accurate and reliable it is for my needs. So I'm thinking about the ways to do it..

Comment: I cant imagine why nobody is getting what you are asking, i tried lockito but it doesn't seem to work, i wish i could find a way to test this without actually getting up and walk around to test it

Comment: Did you ever find any answer to that? I am wanting to play around as well, but find i rather hard to walk/ drive the whole time. Would be awesome to emulate some of the events.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite general, so I will give the general answer. Basically, you shouldn't test external APIs and libraries, so you should have named this thread differently. What you want to do is to emulate the specific behavior of the API.

You can do it in the following way:

- use Dependency Injection library like Dagger and hide API
  implementation behind the interface
- add library implementation of the interface
- add another stub implementation simulating behavior you want to achieve
- in Gradle configuration, you can assign proper
  implementation of the interface or use flavors functionality to
  configure build variants (e.g. awareness-testing, production, etc.)

Remember to exclude Stub class from production build.

I'm not sure about exact implementation, but I'd go, more or less, this way.

Moreover, you can test specific functionalities via unit tests